# Set focus to Project Explorer with Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to ensure that the standard Eclipse Project Explorer is getting focussed every time I activate one of the views of my plugin.
Is there a way to programmatically set the focus to the Project Explorer, making it active?

Comment: Everytime i activate one of my views, they will get focussed (usual way). For some reason, when i rightclick on projects in the project explorer, the project explorer doesn't become foccused, which makes it unable to launch my property testers. That's why i needed a solution for that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell Eclipse to show and activate the view.

Project Explorer's id is `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer`

So something like:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

page.showView("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```